# how to include aspose.pdf.cpp in vs c++ project?

Tags: c++, aspose.pdf, pdf-writer

I am trying to implement this basic example  https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/cpp/hello-world-example/ but I am getting errors that MakeObject, Document and TextFragment are not defined.
I was developing on vscode but then I realized that aspose can be downloaded through nuget in vs so I switched to vs thinking that adding aspose will be automatically integrated in my project dependencies or something, but no it didn't and I don't know currently how to include it (my use case is also very basic I tried hummuspdf/PDF-Writer but also I didn't knew how to implement it or include it, maybe it isn't as simple as `#include "file.h"` ? )

Comment: We logged this issue as PDFCPP-1931 in our issue tracking system. We will inform you once this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "Aspose.PDF.Cpp/Document.h"
#include "Aspose.PDF.Cpp/SaveFormat.h"

using namespace Aspose::Pdf;
using namespace System;

int main()
{
    auto doc = MakeObject<Document>(u"Example.pdf");
    doc->Save(u"Example.docx", SaveFormat::DocX);
}
```